# How to convert varchar to numbers in sql developer

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I trying to use list of numbers like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id in (list_of_ids)
```

this is part of sql procedure and the variable 'list_of_ids' is varchar and it contains id's like this: 1,2,3,4,5........
How can i use this list and this query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this as well. This could be the better solution as it wont require any additional function to create.
oracle regexp_substr will split comma seperated values into different rows and passes to query.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id in 
(SELECT regexp_substr(list_of_ids,'[^,]+', 1, level) FROM dual
connect by regexp_substr(list_of_ids, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ref cursor to construct the sql query, as in this pl/sql block:

```
declare
  list_of_ids    varchar2(100) := '1,3,4'; -- example
  c_cursor       sys_refcursor;
  result         number;
begin
  open c_cursor for ( 'SELECT id '||
                      'FROM   users '||
                      'WHERE  id in ('||list_of_ids||')'
                    );
  fetch c_cursor into result;
  while c_cursor%found
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('ID='||to_char(result)); 
    fetch c_cursor into result;
  end loop;
  close c_cursor;
end;
/
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this solution in your project.
Add a new user function that returns a table.
Code is below:

```
CREATE   FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text varchar(8000), @delimiter
 varchar(20) = ' ')
RETURNS @Strings TABLE
(    
  position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  value varchar(8000)   
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @index int 
SET @index = -1 
WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0) 
 BEGIN  
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text)  
    IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0)  
      BEGIN   
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
          BREAK  
      END  
    IF (@index > 1)  
      BEGIN   
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))   
        SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))  
      END  
    ELSE 
      SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
    END
  RETURN
END
```

And then call it from your stored procedure like below.

```
DECLARE @list_of_ids AS VARCHAR(100)

SET @list_of_ids = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'


SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id in (SELECT value FROM dbo.fn_Split(@list_of_ids,','))
```

Comment: Looks like a SQL Server table value function.  Here is an example I found on the oracle equivalent.  However @NoRules answer looks way more elegant.  Makes me wish we had regexp_substr on the microsoft side.   http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/10/27/returning-a-record-set-from-a-function-in-oracle-sql-server-and-db2/