# How to use a comma-separated list of strings as pl/sql stored function parameter inside a "NOT IN" clause of a select statement

Tags: plsql

I have a list of comma-separated strings (from a user input) and I'd like to use this list as a parameter in a pl/sql stored function in a nested sql block using a "not in where clause".

I can't find an elegant way to make it work...

That's what I'm thinking of:

```
CREATE TABLE example ( somevalue VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL);
--
INSERT INTO example VALUES ('value1');
INSERT INTO example VALUES ('value2');
INSERT INTO example VALUES ('value3');
--
SELECT * FROM example;
--
CREATE OR REPLACE
  FUNCTION resultmaker(
      ignoreList IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    result VARCHAR2(4000);
  BEGIN
    result  := 'Here is my calculated result, using ignorelist=' || ignoreList || ':'     || CHR(10);
    FOR rec IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT somevalue
    FROM example
    WHERE somevalue NOT IN resultmaker.ignoreList -- here's my issue, the NOT IN     clause using the parameter value
    )
    LOOP
      result := result || 'not in ignorelist: ' || rec.somevalue || CHR(10);
    END LOOP;
    result := result || '.' || CHR(10);
    --
    RETURN result;
  END resultmaker;
  /
--
-- simulate function call with user input 'value2, value3'
SELECT resultmaker('value2, value3') FROM dual; -- doesn't work  
--
DROP TABLE example;
DROP FUNCTION resultmaker;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert varchar to numbers in sql developer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479708/how-to-convert-varchar-to-numbers-in-sql-developer)

Comment: Thanks, similar problem! My basic problem was not knowing about dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution using dynamic sql for my original question above:

```
CREATE TABLE example ( somevalue VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL);
--
INSERT INTO example VALUES ('value1');
INSERT INTO example VALUES ('value2');
INSERT INTO example VALUES ('value3');
--
SELECT * FROM example;
--
CREATE OR REPLACE
  FUNCTION resultmaker(
      ignoreList IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    result VARCHAR2(4000);
    example_cursor sys_refcursor;
    rec example.somevalue%type;
  BEGIN
    result := 'Here is my calculated result, using ignorelist=' || ignoreList || ':' || CHR(10);
    OPEN example_cursor FOR ( 'SELECT DISTINCT somevalue FROM example WHERE somevalue NOT IN (' || ignoreList || ')' );
    FETCH example_cursor INTO rec;
    WHILE example_cursor%found
    LOOP
      result := result || 'not in ignorelist: ' || rec || CHR(10);
      FETCH example_cursor INTO rec;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE example_cursor;
    result := result || '.' || CHR(10);
    --
    RETURN result;
  END resultmaker; 
/
--
-- simulate function call with user input 'value2', 'value3'
SELECT resultmaker('''value2'', ''value3''') FROM dual;
--
DROP TABLE example;
DROP FUNCTION resultmaker;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the parameter like `'"value2","value3"'` and have your statement replace the double quote with single quotes like `REPLACE(@Param1,'"','''')`.

Call to function:  `SELECT * FROM Function1('"value2","value3"')`

Inside function:  `NOT IN REPLACE(@Param1,'"','''')`

Answer (score 0):

In every case you should parse that input. As there is no built-in string tokenizer in PL/SQL (at least I couldn't find it) You may want to look into these options,

http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2007/06/20/my-version-of-sql-string-to-table-tokenizer/

[Does PL/SQL have an equivalent StringTokenizer to Java's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520733/does-pl-sql-have-an-equivalent-stringtokenizer-to-javas)

After you parsed the string, you may create a new string like:

```
not_in_statement varchar2(1000);
CURSOR c1 IS select token from tokenized_strings_table;
BEGIN
    not_in_statement := '('
    FOR rec IN c1 LOOP
        not_in_statement := not_in_statement || '''||rec.token||'''||','
    END LOOP
    not_in_statement := not_in_statement||')'
END

SELECT DISTINCT somevalue
FROM example
WHERE somevalue NOT IN not_in_statement
```

You may need to make it dynamic SQL, I did not have time to try.

Comment: Thanks Canburak for the answer! Pointing me to "dynamic sql" was the key. 

I can control the representation of the comma-separated list outside of pl/sql, so a solution using dynamic sql is fine for me.

Comment: I'll post my new solution as an answer, as soon as I can (I have not enough reputation at the moment and have to wait 8h)

Answer (score 0):

The classic and probably correct solution would be to use PL/SQL table passing it as prameter...

Answer (score 0):

There are some good solutions at asktom.oracle.com regarding taking a string of values and dynamically creating an IN clause for them:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425